# html5 video tag setting src programmatically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, video

I need to run a video file for this iam using video element.
  The anomaly which iam seeing right now is that if iam setting the src programmatically then the file is not playing.
  While the same path if iam directly giving in src then the video is playing.

The Video resides in Videos folder of solution, so i dont think there is any access issues.

Below code directly assigns the src for video - Playing the file.

```
  function ShowModalPopup() {
    //$find("mpe").show();
    //return false;
    var param1 = new Date();
    var month = param1.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = param1.getDate();
    var param2 = (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + param1.getFullYear() + ' ' + param1.getHours() + ':' + param1.getMinutes() + ':' + param1.getSeconds();
    $("#<%= hdnStartDateTime.ClientID %>").val(param2);
    var url = $get("<%=lnkVideoLink.ClientID %>").value;
    alert(url);
    //$get("video").src = url;
    $('[id*="MyVdo"]').attr('src', '../../MS_RIT_Training_Videos/REITIworkatTest.mp4');//type='video/mp4'
    //$('[id*="MyVdo"]')[0].play();
    $find("mpe").show();
    return false;
}
```

Below code programmatically assigning src - Not Playing the video

```
function ShowModalPopup() {
    //$find("mpe").show();
    //return false;
    var param1 = new Date();
    var month = param1.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = param1.getDate();
    var param2 = (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + param1.getFullYear() + ' ' + param1.getHours() + ':' + param1.getMinutes() + ':' + param1.getSeconds();
    $("#<%= hdnStartDateTime.ClientID %>").val(param2);
    var url = $get("<%=lnkVideoLink.ClientID %>").value;
    alert(url);
    //$get("video").src = url;
    // $('[id*="MyVdo"]').attr('src', '../../MS_RIT_Training_Videos/REITIworkatTest.mp4');//type='video/mp4'
    $('[id*="MyVdo"]').attr('src', url);//type='video/mp4'
    //$('[id*="MyVdo"]')[0].play();
    $find("mpe").show();
    return false;
}
```

For Kenneth :

[image]

Alert:

[image]

Comment: In generall your code looks ok. Check the values of `url` again. I'm actually pretty sure the problem is in there, if the first function runs without any problem.

Comment: Implementing Kenneth code is playing the video now, but before that I get this error. I need to hit continue only then the video plays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the URLs are the same (hardcoded and the one you get from the element)?

also you can try to load the video programmatically after you set it

```
$('[id*="MyVdo"]')[0].load();
```

Comment: Another question is not an answer. Post it as a comment!

Comment: An error is being shown on Runtime " Object doesn't support property or method 'load'". But the video is playing now on Continue.

Comment: if you execute $('[id*="MyVdo"]')[0] in developer tools or alert it. What element shows? It should be the video element

Comment: Please see the error snapshot. I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you do alert( $('[id*="MyVdo"]')[0]) before the load line and post that so i can see?

Comment: I changed to alert( $('[id*="MyVdo"]')[1]) , which i actually the Video Element. Now it worked. Thanks Kenneth.

Comment: Yes thats what i was going for, to find your actual video element :D You should give your VIDEO element a unique id and work with that to set your src and load it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115838/discussion-between-rishabh-and-kenneth).