# HTML 5 Video : Video not playing on TEST Server

Tags: asp.net, html, video

I have been working on html5 video where I need to play video. The Video resides in Solution folder.

Please visit this link in which iam able to run video in localhost : 
[yesterday discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052993/html5-video-tag-setting-src-programmatically)

I have created a folder in the same solution and the path which iam providing to src is **..\..\TrainingFolder\Filename.mp4**

Iam able to do that in local solution, but when i created same folder structure in TEST server and migrated the code. The video is not playing.

The below code is working fine in local environment that is localhost but not in TEST server.

```
  $("#<%= hdnStartDateTime.ClientID %>").val(param2);
    var url = $get("<%=lnkVideoLink.ClientID %>").value;
    alert(url);
    $('[id*="MyVdo"]').attr('src', url);//type='video/mp4'
    $('[id*="MyVdo"]')[1].load();
    //Show Panel
    $find("mpe").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it as there was no MIME type associated with IIS for mp4.
I added a MIME type and i got it.